# Передача информации в контроллер

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Пользуюсь плагином [jquery-confirm](https://github.com/craftpip/jquery-confirm), по клику на элемент создаю вот такую форму:

```
$.confirm({
    //сама форма
    title: 'Add new event.',
    content: '' +
    '<form id="eventData">' +
    '<div class="form-group">' +
    '<label>Title</label>' +
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Event title.." class="name form-control" name="Title" autocomplete="off" required />' +
    '<br />' +
    '<label>Additional information</label>' +               
    '<textarea placeholder="Add some information about event" name="Additional" class="info form-control" autocomplete="off" required /> </textarea>' +
    '<br />' +
    '<label>Start date</label>' +
    '<input type="date" class="startDate form-control" name="StartDate" required />' +
    '<br />' +
    '<label>End date</label>' +
    '<input type="date" class="endDate form-control" name="EndDate" required />' +
    '</div>' + 
    '</form>',

    buttons: {
       formSubmit: {
           text: 'Save',
           btnClass: 'btn-success',
           action: function () {  
               //беру информацию из формы 
               var titleF = this.$content.find('.name').val();
               var additionalF = this.$content.find('.info').val();
               var startDateF = this.$content.find('.startDate').val();
               var endDateF = this.$content.find('.endDate').val();

               //посылаю в контроллер
               $.ajax({
                   url: 'Calendar/CreateEvent',
                   data: { title: titleF, additional: additionalF, startDate: startDateF, endDate: endDateF},
                   dataType: "JSON",
                   success: function (data) {
                              var event = { id: data.item.Id, title: data.item.Title, start: toDateFromJson(data.item.EndDate) }
                              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true);                                        
                            }
                        });                            
                      }                            
                    },                  
        cancel: {}, 
     },
});
```

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку `Save`, то в контроллер передаются значения из `input`'ов. В контроллере я эти значения добавляю в модель и отправляю на другие слои.

Контроллер:

```
public ActionResult CreateEvent(string title, string additional, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    BLL.Model.CalendarModelItem item = new BLL.Model.CalendarModelItem {
        Title = title,
        Additional = additional,
        StartDate = startDate,
        EndDate = endDate
    };

            calDbProv.Add(item);


            return Json( new { status = "success", item }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Я бы хотел понять, как из формы, которая создается по клику отправлять в контроллер сразу модель с помощью `ajax`?

Вот код модели:

```
public class CalendarModelItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Additional { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Сразу модель отправлять нельзя, но можно отправить все данные, как я и делал, далее модель их принимает и все работает.

```
public ActionResult CreateEvent(BLL.Model.CalendarModelItem item)
{ 
    calDbProv.Add(item);

    return Json( new { status = "success", item }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```